# Reload system config to get last saved values

Tags: custom-options, cache, configuration, core-config-data

When I save new value of a custom option in system config that new value is not available *in the same request*. For example, somewhere at the beginning of a controller action in a custom module I save the new value:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('some/custom/option1', 'ABC');
```

And then at the end of that action when I try to get the value of this option from config:

```
$newValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('some/custom/option1');
```

it doesn't return `ABC` but the old value of this option. I understand it gets this old value from cached config.

**Question:** Is there a way to programmatically refresh/reload the system config to get the real last saved values from system config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();`

Comment: Thank you. Does this have any important side effects which I should know about before using it? :)

Comment: @zitix afaik there is no side effect. This method invalidates the config cache and performs a complete reload of the configurations. The script runtime is of course longer.